# BlackBerry10 android run-time | Which os version should I select during uploading

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-android, blackberry-world

I uploading bb10 app to appworld and I can select the following os version

- 1.0.0
- 1.0.3
- 1.0.6
- 1.0.7
- 1.0.8
- 2.0.0
- 2.0.1
- 2.1.0
- 10.0.0
- 10.0.10
- 10.1.0
- 10.2.0

Which one should I select? what does it depend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android support on BlackBerry is as follows:

v2.3.3 (Gingerbread):

- [BlackBerry PlayBook (v 1.x - 2.x)](https://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/android/documentation/mastertopic_playbook.html)
- [BlackBerry 10.0 - 10.1](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/bb_runtime_release_notes.html)

v4.2.2 (Jelly Bean):

- [BlackBerry 10.2 +](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/bb_runtime_release_notes.html)

Answer (score 1):

<= 2.x : It concerns Playbooks only, it supports Android, Flash, Webworks or native but not cascades.

> = 10.x : It concerns BB10 phones devices. If you develop with cascades, just take care that you are not using 10.0 unexistant functionnalities (such as validators, ...) by testing with a simulator.

Comment: Could you please clarify yet one moment. Is it possible to build a single bar for bot Blackberry Phone and PlayBook? And which version should I select in this case?

Comment: What is the language that you use?

Comment: Java for Android-runtime and C++ for BB10 native applications

Comment: For Android you have nothing to do to make your bar compatible with Playbook (except supporting Android 2.3). 
For C++ if you use Cascades, it'll be for phones only. If you use Core Native, I recommend to test it before releasing the same bar on Playbook